# Unlimited streaming with tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I would like to create an ulimited streaming from Twitter API, using Tweepy, so my code is :

```
import tweepy

consumer_key = ""
consumer_secret = ""
key = ""
secret = ""

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(key, secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth, retry_count=10, retry_delay=5, retry_errors=set([401, 404, 500, 503]), wait_on_rate_limit=True)
c = tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q="mongodb",include_entities=True,rpp=100).items()

import jsonpickle
import json



counter = 0
while True:
    try:
        tweet = c.next()
        tweet = jsonpickle.encode(tweet)
        tweet = json.loads(tweet)       
        col.insert(tweet)       
        counter += 1
        print ("TweetNumber %s " % counter )
    except tweepy.TweepError:
            time.sleep(60 * 15)
            continue
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

`col` is a MongoDB collection, I don't have any problems with this.
The problem is that the streamin stopped at 5K tweets !

How can you explain this ? Any suggestions ? Thanks !

Comment: How big is each insert? Is your system 32 bit? MongoDB has a 2gb limit on 32bit systems. This could be a reason.

Comment: 32. I haven't any error telling that the DB limit is reached (I don't thin that 5K tweets will occupy 2GB of size .. I haven't any error at all ! Seems like I streamed all possible tweets !

Comment: Googling around, it looks like you can follow up to 5000 names with Twitter’s streaming API. Could that be the limit you’re running in to?

Comment: It was 5K tweets, not 5k users. I am not searching for people but for tweets containing specefic hashtags.

Comment: You might try the [Streaming API](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/streaming_how_to.html) with a filter.  It doesn't give you 100% of the tweets matching your search, but neither does the search/tweets REST API.